# Android Barcode scanner with inventory

Tags: java, android, inventory

recently I have created a barcode scanner application which used an array to store the product barcode and use that array to match the scanned 
barcode result to display information which is working fine for now I guess.

But for now, I would like to add an feature, that is after scanning the item and the product information is displayed such as product name, price, etc, 
the application will display an alert box to ask the users whether to add this scanned product into the inventory or not.

If the users press Yes, that product will stored to the shopping bag/inventory list, if the user press No, then that scanned product will not be added to the shopping bag/inventory, and the user can access to it later to know how much they will be spending on all those added product.

For now, my application can only scan and display result only. Can I have any suggestion on how to add those features to my application that I mentioned above ? I'm glad if you could have a look on my source code to see what you can do about it or maybe help me add in those features to my application if can. Below is the link for my source code .

http://www.mediafire.com/file/grpxx9evctbnvhv/BarcodeReader.rar

Comment: What is you want to know about the storage or?

Comment: to add that features and the invenotory storage to my barcode application

Comment: do you want to add it in the server or on the device itself.

Comment: the device itself only .... can u help me with that ?

Comment: Yes , I can help you . but in which area you are stuck

Comment: stuck at the inventory part and alert box to allow user to press yes or no . Would like to have a look on my source code ? I don't know to add the features to my application

Comment: post some source code then

Comment: here u go bro ...

http://www.mediafire.com/file/grpxx9evctbnvhv/BarcodeReader.rar

Comment: am wondering if issit possible for you to help me to add those features to my source code ?

Comment: it sounds what you want is to store the scanned barcodes in a local database, so I recommend learning about sqlite on android as a next step. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Thank for the suggestion trooper. But for now, I'm more focus in this feature, that is after scanning the item and the product information is displayed such as product name, price, etc, the application will display an alert box to ask the users whether to add this scanned product into the inventory or not. 

If the users press Yes, that product will store to the shopping bag/inventory list and the user can access to it later to know how much they will be spending on all this product.
Can I have any suggestion on how to add those features to my application?

Comment: anyone can help pls ?